# merge databricks SQL of different decimal datatypes

Tags: sql, types, append, databricks

I have a Databricks SQL search that results in a data type `decimal(18,0)`

I want to append the results of this search into an existing table (`df.write.format("delta").mode("append").save("a_path")`) but cannot because it has a data type of `decimal(38,18)`

When I try to append, the error I get is:
`AnalysisException: Failed to merge fields 'id' and 'id'. Failed to merge decimal types with incompatible precision 38 and 18 & scale 18 and 0;`

Is there a way around this?

I tried to cast the result of the search to a decimal(38,18) `select cast(id decimal(38,18))...` but this did not work

Any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

As a work around, I converted the SQL search columns into decimal type in pyspark, and then continued to merge:

```
query="""select * from ..."""

df=spark.sql(query)
df=df.withColumn("id",df["id"].cast(DecimalType(38,18)))
df.write.format("delta").mode("append").save("a_path")
```